# T-SQL Update based on subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery

I've come a trouble with updating with sub-query where subquery should return value based on some key in row of updated cell. Usually it would be working with table like this:

```
╔══════════════════════════════╗
║ Key1  Key2    Value   Other  ║
╠══════════════════════════════╣
║ Key11 Key21   Val1    Other1 ║
║ Key12 Key22   Val2    Other2 ║
║ Key13 Key23   Val3    Other3 ║
║ Key14 Key24   Val4    Other4 ║
╚══════════════════════════════╝
```

And I'd like to do something like:

```
UPDATE Table T1 
SET T1.Value = (SELECT T2.Other 
                FROM Table T2 
                WHERE T2.Key2 IN ("SOME CONSTRAINT")) 
WHERE T1.Key1 = T2.Key2
```

I know this can't work. Outer where clause can't see the `T2.Key2`.

Other case would be updating one table based on other table.

Say `Table1` is

```
╔═════════════════╗
║  Key    Value   ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ Key1   Val1     ║
║ Key2   Val2     ║
║ Key3   Val3     ║
║ Key4   Val4     ║
╚═════════════════╝
```

And `Table2`

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║ OtherKey OtherValue  ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ Key1      Val1       ║
║ Key2      Val2       ║
║ Key3      Val3       ║
║ Key4      Val4       ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

Again I want to do something like

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 
SET T1.Value = (SELECT T2.Value 
                FROM Table2 T2 
                WHERE "SOME CONDITION") 
WHERE T1.Key = T2.OtherKey
```

Once again outer `WHERE` can't see the key in sub query. If I do it without outer `WHERE` in both cases I get error that sub-query returns more than one value which is not allowed.

This will actually work without the second `WHERE` if its a `INSERT` statement instead of `UPDATE` one, only way I managed to get this to work for UPDATE is with loops or cursors.

Outline of 3rd variation of situation would be if I have a result set like (Key, Value) with as much value pairs as I have rows in table to be updated and want to assign "Value" to the updated column based on "Key" from set and some key from row to be updated.

Comment: Have you looked at using an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`?

Comment: This is a common way to think of building sql queries by inexperienced developers. They try to build their data sets into queries and 'glue' them together, whereas often the same result can be achieved with cleaner syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 17):

For the first case, I don't see why the subquery is needed, wouldn't be just the same as:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Value = Other
WHERE Key2 IN ("SOME CONSTRAINT")
AND Key1 = Key2
```

And the second `UPDATE` can be done with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.Value = T2.Value 
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.Key = T2.OtherKey
```

Comment: Well actual cases were a bit more complicated, I just tried to make simple illustrations. Still thanks a lot, didn't consider using joins in a update.

Also, could I (and how) use WITH or some similar syntax so that subquery gives me value to use and the key to match on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax

```
update table1
set whatever
from table1 join table2 on something
join (subquery goes here) temp on something
```